# Create calendars directly from iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a friend whose iPhone (latest gen, relatively recent iOS but I don't think it's fully up to date) doesn't have any calendars on it.  I don't think it's ever been sync'd, and even if it had, she has Windows 7 (which doesn't by default come with a calendar app), and she doesn't have Outlook.  So my idea was to sync the device with a calendar app to force it to create a calendar, but that's obviously not going to work here.

UPDATE: She just called me to say she restarted the phone and the default cal came back (???).

But the question stands:  is it possible to create a calendar without doing any sort of sync whatsoever, just directly from the phone?  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I've enabled iCloud a while ago, I'm not sure if that'll work the same way for local calendars.

You should see a button that says *Calendars* in the top left corner in iCal on your iPhone. Tap it, then tap *Edit*. You should now be able to add a calendar and assign a title and color.

Please let me know if this works for you.